# Rails/Devise Errno::ENOENT on lockfile after server crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, openid

I've got a Rails 3.2.5 app using Devise, with OpenID for authentication (Google), running on nginx/unicorn.

Today, my server crashed. I restarted. Now sign-in is not working. Here's what happens:

- Signed-out user accesses app
- Signed-out user redirected to `/users/sign_in`
- User clicks 'Sign-in with GMail' button
- **500 error.** In the log file, I see:

  ```
  Started GET "/users/auth/google" for ...
  Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - /tmp/temp/tmp20120801-4155-1scxc9o.lock):
  ```

How can I resolve this error? I'm not even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an access issue. Not sure of the root cause, but no doubt it has something to do with some mistake I made when configuring the app.

**To resolve:**

```
$ cd /tmp
$ chmod 777 temp
$ chmod 777 associations
$ chmod 777 nonces
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your OpenID filestore is setup correctly, ie..

`OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp')`

(Notice the . in front of the /tmp)